# How to Implement Dark mode on Blogger & Comment Box

Tags: css, blogger

Recently, I've developed the Dark mode version in my Blog (Blogger). Everything is looking good. But only one problem is, I cant not change the blogger default comment box color. I've attached a screenshot.

Hope someone will help me...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That comment box is in an iframe and cannot be styled with CSS from the outside.

The solution is to go into the Blogger settings. Scroll down to comments. Under comment location, choose either full page or popup window.

[image: The Blogger settings]